# Prolog Output Gives False After True

Tags: prolog, prolog-toplevel

I have a prolog program to represent the flights between two states with their costs.

My program is this:

```
flight(newyork,washington,7). %its mean that there is a flight between both washington and newyork, newyork and washington with cost 7. 
flight(lasvegas,losangeles,4).
flight(california,arizona,8).

route(A,B,C):-
    flight(A,B,C);flight(B,A,C). %there is a route if there is a flight between A and B with cost C `OR` B and A with cost C.
```

Now, When I write a query like this:

```
?-route(washington,newyork,7).
```

its give me `true`. This query works good for me.

But when I write this query:

```
?-route(newyork,washington,7).
```

Its gives me firtsly `true` and after `false`.But I don't want this. I want only `true`,why it gives `false` after the `true`? Why it gives two outputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Its gives me firtsly `true` and after `false`. But I don't want this. I want only `true`, why it gives `false` after the `true`? Why it gives two outputs?

Because Prolog has builtin backtracking. After it proposes a first solution, it will report that solution, but then it will backtrack in search for another solution.

Depending on the exact query, Prolog can know in advance that there are no backtracking options. Prolog evaluates the facts/clauses of a predicate top-down, so that means that if it for example succeed with the last clause (and there are no recursive calls), it knows for sure that it has exhaustively searched all options.

Here you write:

```
route(A, B, C):-
    flight(A, B, C);
    flight(B, A, C).
```

So that means if you call `route(newyork, washington, 7).`, it will first call `flight(newyork, washington, 7)`.and that succeeds (it is even the first `flight/3` fact), but there are still options how it could succeed: perhaps there is another `flight(newyork, washington, 7)` fact, so this could give `true` a second time.

Most Prolog systems however have advanced lookup strategies to see that this is the only `flight/3` fact with `newyork` as first parameter, so a modern Prolog system, will typically know in advance that there is no hope to find another `flight/3` fact, but that does not mean we are done.

You defined, in the body of your `route/3` clause `flight(B, A, C)`, so Prolog will start a search for `flight/3`, but with swapped locations. It will thus, after it has reported the first solution, continue the query, and call `flight(washington, newyork, 7)` in the hope to find another solution.

If the query uses variables, this is quite useful, since in the proposed solutions, the the values that are assigned to the variables can (and very often *are*) different, so this can be used as a search tool.

You can use the [**once/1** [swi-doc]](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=once/1) meta-predicate to evaluate the call once. In that case either the predicate succeeds (and unifies variables), or it does not (and fails). Furthermore it is of course still possible that the predicate raises an error, or got stuck in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 3):

Your definition of the `route/2` predicate is not deterministic. If the left goal in disjunction succeeds, it's also possible that the right goal would also succeed. I.e. the disjunction implies a choice-point:

```
?- route(newyork,washington,7).
true ;
false.
```

When you type the `;` you're asking Prolog for an alternative solution. The Prolog engine backtracks to the choice point and tries the right goal. As this goal fails, the Prolog top-level prints `false` to let you know that an alternative solution could not be found.

Comment: What should I do for getting only `true` not both `true` and `false`?